# Angular - select object from JSON data through $routeParams

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, ngroute

I'm trying to display data from my json file which looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "category":"category1",
    "link":"category1",
    "expand":false,
    "keyword":"category1, category1 online, category1 something"
  },
  {
    "category":"category2",
    "link":"category2",
    "expand":false,
    "keyword":"category2, category2 online, category2 something"
  }
]
```

I'm also using $routeProvider in my controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'MyControllers'
]);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) { 
    $routeProvider.when('/:itemName', {templateUrl: function(param){ 
        return'partials/'+ param.itemName +'.html';
    }, controller: 'ContentCtrl'});
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/category1'});
}]);

var MyControllers = angular.module('MyControllers', ['ngAnimate']);

MyControllers.controller('ContentCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.meta = data;
        $scope.whichItem = $routeParams.itemName.indexOf()+1;
  });
}]);
```

And finally for a template:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section ng-view>
        <h1>{{meta[whichItem].h1}}</h1>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

So the problem is that the param `$whichItem` always returns 0 as a value. It doesn't want to reaload when I change my route to `/category2` for example and shows the same keywords from json data. What is wrong with this?

Comment: [String.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) indefOf('What?") add what are you looking for inside IndexOf method

Comment: Ok. I'm trying this: $scope.whichItem = $routeParams.itemName.indexOf()+1; because normal value of the routeparam doesn't work: $scope.whichItem = $routeParams.itemName;

Comment: What works is: {{meta[0].h1}} and {{meta[1].h1}} then I get keywords from category1 and category2. {{meta[whichItem].h1}} doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

It appears you want to obtain the last character of the `itemName` which is an integer and use this integer to determine the right object to obtain from the JSON array.

When the application is routed to `category2`, the `itemName` is `category2`. This means the object to be obtained from the JSON array is the 2nd one; the object at index `1` in the array.

You can obtain this by slicing the string at the last index and converting it into an integer.

```
$scope.whichItem = parseInt($routeParams.itemName.slice(-1), 10) - 1;
```

Comment: Not at all. I'm trying to use **$scope.whichItem = $routeParams.itemName** as index to get the appropriate value from JSON, in this example: keyword. So I'm using **{{meta[whichItem].keyword}}** but it doesn't fetch anything...

Comment: I'm trying your method but it seems not working. Maybe because of parseInt()?

Comment: Can you inspect the value of $routeParams? You can use `console.log`.

Comment: I meant `console.log($routeParams)` in the controller.

Comment: Did you input the line exactly as I wrote it? I see nothing wrong with it.

If you need to test it, type this in your console:
`var $routeParams = { itemName: 'category1' };`
`parseInt($routeParams.itemName.slice(-1), 10) - 1;`

You should get a `0` which is the correct value.

Comment: This code doesn't do anything to be honest. I still get **Object { itemName="category1"}** in the console...

Comment: What is the cause of this? Any ideas?